# How to make a logical statement which finds a year between/in two date columns?

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I have a problem executing something in R which maybe isn't hard but I simply can't figure it out.

Let's say I have the following dataframe with only two date columns: date_started and date_ended.

```
df <- data.frame(date_started=as.Date(c("1990-02-01","1995-03-04","1997-04-01","1999-01-11","1993-04-04")),
date_ended=as.Date(c("1993-08-12","1999-07-06","2000-06-05","1999-12-01","1996-07-08")))
```

They represent the start and end dates of the treatment of patients.
Now I would like to add new columns which are either 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) when the person was treated in a certain year.

The result columns should be:

```
df$year_1990 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
df$year_1991 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
df$year_1992 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
df$year_1993 <- c(1,0,0,0,1)
df$year_1994 <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
df$year_1995 <- c(0,1,0,0,1)
df$year_1996 <- c(0,1,0,0,1)
df$year_1997 <- c(0,1,1,0,0)
df$year_1998 <- c(0,1,1,0,0)
df$year_1999 <- c(0,1,1,1,0)
df$year_2000 <- c(0,0,1,0,0)
```

So I can count for each year how many people were treated.

I have tried and looked for a solution but simply can't find it.
I've tried ifelse statements and the between function but I did not manage to solve this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate_all(ymd) %>% mutate(new = map2(year(date_started), year(date_ended),  ~ seq(.x, .y) %>% set_names(str_c('year_', .)) %>% as.list ))  %>% unnest_wider(new) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('year')), ~ +(!is.na(.)))`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do not have the proper package versions to run this solution. However, the other answers already solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option would be to convert to `Date` class, extract the 'year' with `format`, get a sequence, `stack` the `list` of `vector`s to a 2 column data.frame, and get frequency count with `table`

```
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) as.numeric(x):as.numeric(y),
  format(as.Date(df$date_started), "%Y"), format(as.Date(df$date_ended), "%Y"))
dfn <- cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix( table(stack(lst1)[2:1])))
row.names(dfn) <- NULL
colnames(dfn)[-(1:2)] <- paste0("year_", colnames(dfn)[-(1:2)])
dfn
#  date_started date_ended year_1990 year_1991 year_1992 year_1993 year_1994 year_1995 year_1996 year_1997 year_1998 year_1999 year_2000
#1   1990-02-01 1993-08-12         1         1         1         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#2   1995-03-04 1999-07-06         0         0         0         0         0         1         1         1         1         1         0
#3   1997-04-01 2000-06-05         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         1         1         1
#4   1999-01-11 1999-12-01         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
#5   1993-04-04 1996-07-08         0         0         0         1         1         1         1         0         0         0         0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(gtools)
df %>%
   mutate_all(ymd) %>%
   mutate(new = map2(year(date_started), year(date_ended),
          ~ seq(.x, .y) %>% 
             set_names(str_c('year_', .)) %>%
             as.list )) %>%
   unnest_wider(new) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('year')), ~ +(!is.na(.))) %>%
   select(date_started, date_ended, mixedsort(names(.)[-(1:2)]))
# A tibble: 5 x 13
#  date_started date_ended year_1990 year_1991 year_1992 year_1993 year_1994 year_1995 year_1996 year_1997 year_1998 year_1999 year_2000
#  <date>       <date>         <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 1990-02-01   1993-08-12         1         1         1         1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
#2 1995-03-04   1999-07-06         0         0         0         0         0         1         1         1         1         1         0
#3 1997-04-01   2000-06-05         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         1         1         1
#4 1999-01-11   1999-12-01         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
#5 1993-04-04   1996-07-08         0         0         0         1         1         1         1         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first option works without any problems. The second tidyverse option does not work for my because of older package versions. Will have to update a lot to check. Again thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(var = list(seq(as.numeric(substr(date_started, 1, 4)), 
                       as.numeric(substr(date_ended, 1, 4)), 
                       1))) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 unnest(var) %>%
 mutate(var = paste0("year_", var),
        val = 1) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "var", values_from = "val", values_fill = list(val = 0))

  date_started date_ended year_1990 year_1991 year_1992 year_1993 year_1995 year_1996 year_1997 year_1998 year_1999
  <date>       <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 1990-02-01   1993-08-12         1         1         1         1         0         0         0         0         0
2 1995-03-04   1999-07-06         0         0         0         0         1         1         1         1         1
3 1997-04-01   2000-06-05         0         0         0         0         0         0         1         1         1
4 1999-01-11   1999-12-01         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         1
5 1993-04-04   1996-07-08         0         0         0         1         1         1         0         0         0
# … with 2 more variables: year_2000 <dbl>, year_1994 <dbl>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I do not have the proper Tidyr version (for function pivot_wider) to run this solution at the moment. The solutions below have solved the problem without this issue.

Comment: Yes, `pivot_wider()` is from the newest `tidyr` version :)

Answer (score 2):

Combining base R with `lubridate::year` yields a succinct and simple
solution:

```
year_bool <- sapply(1990:2000, function(y) {
    as.integer(y >= year(df$date_started) & y <= year(df$date_ended))
})
colnames(year_bool) <- paste('year', 1990:2000, sep = '_')

cbind(df, year_bool)

##   date_started date_ended year_1990 year_1991 year_1992 year_1993
## 1   1990-02-01 1993-08-12         1         1         1         1
## 2   1995-03-04 1999-07-06         0         0         0         0
## 3   1997-04-01 2000-06-05         0         0         0         0
## 4   1999-01-11 1999-12-01         0         0         0         0
## 5   1993-04-04 1996-07-08         0         0         0         1
##   year_1994 year_1995 year_1996 year_1997 year_1998 year_1999 year_2000
## 1         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
## 2         0         1         1         1         1         1         0
## 3         0         0         0         1         1         1         1
## 4         0         0         0         0         0         1         0
## 5         1         1         1         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! This options also seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution using @Andy Rominger's logic:

```
# Create a vector with that's values are all the years between the two date vectors: 

year_range <- eval(parse(text = paste(range(unlist(lapply(df, 

                              function(x){x <- as.integer(gsub("[-].*", "", x))}))), 

                collapse = ":")))

# Using Andy Rominger's logic, but in base determine if date is between the two years: 

new_df <- cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(sapply(year_range, function(x){

    as.integer(x >= as.numeric(gsub("[-].*", "", df$date_started)) & 

                                 x <= as.numeric(gsub("[-].*", "", (df$date_ended))))

        }

      )

    ),

    c(paste0("year_", year_range))

  )

)
```

Data:

```
df <- 
  structure(
    list(
      date_started = structure(c(7336, 9193, 9952, 10602,
                                 8494), class = "Date"),
      date_ended = structure(c(8624, 10778,
                               11113, 10926, 9685), class = "Date")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-5L)
  )
```